# Issues filling up the array in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my ProductCard component I need to be able to create a new item with the addItem method, it does not seem to load the item in the array.

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div v-for="item in TodoItems" :key="item.id">
      <TodoItem :item="item"></TodoItem>
    </div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" v-model="newItemText">
      <button type="submit" v-on:click="addItem">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script async>
import TodoItem from "@/components/TodoItem.vue";

export default {
  name: "ProductCard",
  //hierin defineren we globale variabelen
  components: {TodoItem},
  //in data moeten we altijd iets returnen
  data(){
    return{
      //hierin defineren we alle variabelen die we binnen ons component lokaal gaan gebruiken

      TodoItems: [],
      newItemText: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addItem() {
      // create a new item object and push it to the array
      const newItem = {
        id: this.TodoItems.length,
        text: this.newItemText,
        completed: false
      }
      this.TodoItems.push(newItem);

      console.log('zit er in');
      console.log(this.TodoItems.length);

      // clear the input field
      this.newItemText = '';


    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please check if your addItem function is working or not by adding a console.log statement inside it. If the function is not being called, you can try adding prevent ( v-on:click.prevent ) to your click event listener.

Answer (score 2):

By default when user clicks to a button with type="submit" inside a form (or even just press Enter when form field is focused) - a form will be submitted and a page will be reloaded. This is why you don't see added elements, the page reloads after every adding.

**There are a few ways to prevent this behavior:**

**The First way** - Add ".prevent" modifier to the "v-on:click" directive

```
<form>
  <input type="text" v-model="newItemText">
  <button type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="addItem">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It allows to add an item by clicking to a "Submit" button and by pressing Enter key as well.

**The Second way** - Handle a submit event with ".prevent" modifier in the form element and remove "v-on:click" directive from the button element. The button must be type="submit".

```
<form @submit.prevent="addItem">
  <input type="text" v-model="newItemText">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It also allows to add an item by clicking to a "Submit" button and by hitting Enter.

**The Third way** - Change the button type to "button" **AND** handle the form's submit event with ".prevent" modifier (if you don't handle this event the page will be reloaded when you press Enter key)

```
<form @submit.prevent>
  <input type="text" v-model="newItemText">
  <button type="button" v-on:click="addItem">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It will work too but only when user clicks to the Submit button. Enter key won't work this way.

I would advise to choose the first or the second way.

**FYI:** ".prevent" modifier is just a syntactic sugar for event.preventDefault();

You can check full code and try it here - https://codepen.io/AlekseiKrivo/pen/BaqwMQo

You can read about this more here - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

And about preventDefault here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the button type to `type="button"` if the purpose isn't to actually submit?

Comment: Yes you can but you can't submit a form by hitting the enter key this way. You also can handle a submit event in form element and remove v-on:click directive from the button. I will add this solution in another answer.

Comment: To the prev comment: if you just change type to "button" you still have to prevent default behavior in submit event because a page will be reloaded by pressing Enter button.

Comment: Could you merge your answers, explaining the difference between them? It's more readable that way, and at the moment, this one is only a partial solution, right?

Comment: Sure! I've edited my first answer, I hope it cleaner now. Thanks!